# Polymer 3.0 Uncaught DOM Exception When using Paper-Input

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

When Using `paper-input`, the import throws the following exception

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry.

I haven't done anything besides creating the template for 3.0 and adding the import.

There seems to be an issue with the **Migration Tool**, Google used to update their old components.

Has anybody sorted this already?

Comment: How are you bundling your JS? I had this problem using "flat" imports with Webpack. Basically you have multiple declaration of the same custom element within your bundle.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE** The issue is caused by two different versions of `iron-meta` in `node_modules`: an older version in `./node_modules/@polymer/iron-meta` at `3.0.0-pre.18` (which is already installed with Polymer Starter Kit), and a newer one (`3.0.0-pre.19`) as a dependency of the newly installed `@polymer/paper-input`.

The fix was recently documented in the [Polymer Blog](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-05-25-polymer-elements-3-faq) -- i.e., delete `package-lock.json` and reinstall `node_modules`:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

---

The error's stack trace (below) seems to indicate iron-meta is being registered twice somehow:

```
polymer-fn.js:43 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at Polymer (http://127.0.0.1:8081/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer-fn.js:43:18)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8081/node_modules/@polymer/iron-input/node_modules/@polymer/iron-meta/iron-meta.js:131:1
```

One workaround is to patch `customElements.define` to only run if the element isn't already defined:

```js
const _customElementsDefine = window.customElements.define;
window.customElements.define = function(name, clazz, config) {
  if (!customElements.get(name)) {
    _customElementsDefine.call(window.customElements, name, clazz, config);
  }
};
```

Run this *before* importing any element definition. I confirmed this works for the latest release of `paper-input` on macOS High Sierra, Chrome 66.

---

<sup>Linking the issue you created for reference: [`PolymerElements/paper-input` Issue #652](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/652)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code! I've never used customElements.get, and the documentation... Well, we know the documentation.

I rolled back to Polymer 2.0 as I was in a hurry, but will try this again when things calm down.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I ran into this while going through https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/add-elements. The reinstallation did not help, but you `customElements.define` fix did, thanks!

Comment: @dArignac glad that worked for you. Regarding the reinstall, did you delete both node_modules and package-lock.json beforehand?

Comment: @tony19 yes, so did I

Comment: Neither of those solutions works for me. With and without the patch, I get the same errors. Shown here... https://jpst.it/1kyao

Comment: @Mowzer The error in your [screenshot](http://jpst.it/1kyao) is not the same as the error in question. It seems like you might be missing some dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for this patch. Just like others said, deleting node_modules and package-lock didn't work for me, but your patch solved it. Hope there is a better fix in future, my base.html is sooooo ugly with all of the different helpers and polyfills needed, just so my app can run over multiple browsers >.<

Comment: @tony19 unfortunately I cannot do this as this is a private repo for a client :(

Answer (score 1):

The solution is there on the Polymer website
https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-05-25-polymer-elements-3-faq

1. Basically delete node_modules and package-lock.json
2. Then reinstall, i.e. npm install

It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

as follow the tutorial [add polymer element](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/add-elements),when i import paper-checkbox.js,
I got the same error.
   my solution is just edit file

```
paper-checkbox.js
```

alter the line

```
import '@polymer/polymer/polymer-legacy.js';
```

to

```
import '../../@polymer/polymer/polymer-legacy.js';
```

**Remember always import same module from one place.**

Answer (score 0):

We have a work around for these types of problems. It turns out that polymer 3 doesn't like nesting in node_modules. The trick is to manually remove nestings of modules which are complaining.

[This issue on github against polymer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5407) highlights a scripted solution.